# wordpress author post count limit

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to limit the post for authors , currently i am allowing 2 post no more then 2 post , currently i have few users with more then 2 post so how do i fix my code so it dont allow them to make any more post.

```
 if ($post_count < 2) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
       echo 'You have already posted your maximum number of posts.';
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

as i said few authors have more then 2 post so using this code will allow them to make post because the if stating wil be bypassed because its trying to detect value 2 since they gone past that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wp_insert_post_data filter. And in this filter define your conditions.
So it will be something like that:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'aa_func_20150916080916', 20, 2);
function aa_func_20150916080916($data , $postarr)
{
  $warn = "You have already posted your maximum number of posts";
  $current_user = get_current_user_id();
  $user_post_count = count_user_posts($current_user);
  if($user_post_count >2 ) {
    return wp_die($warn);
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Please note: it's quick answer, you should change code for your purposes.

Docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data